# App is crashing after update release to App store

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have released two versions of my app successfully. But after third version of app is released in App Store, when I downloaded from Appstore the app is getting crashed.

When I try to launch app it is getting crashed immediately, and no crash reports were generated in Xcode Organizer.

The same app is working fine in IPAD/IPHONE SIMULATORS 5.0 and 4.1 versions and also working fine when tested in IPHONE and IPAD devices with IOS 5.1.1 installed (run through XCODE).

No major changes are given other than some image changes and animation changes which are working fine when locally tested.

Here are my logs:

> Jul  5 12:16:01 unknown fairplayd.N90[41] : libMobileGestalt computeUniqueDeviceID: total time for bb to return imei: 0 Jul  5
> 12:16:01 unknown SpringBoard[52] : Unable to obtain a task
> name port right for pid 225: (os/kern) failure Jul  5 12:16:01 unknown
> com.apple.launchd[1] :
> (UIKitApplication:com.myCompany.myApp[0xdaa7]) Exited: Killed: 9 Jul
> 5 12:16:01 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] :
> (UIKitApplication:com.myCompany.myApp[0xdaa7]) Throttling respawn:
> Will start in 2147483647 seconds Jul  5 12:16:01 unknown
> SpringBoard[52] : Application 'myApp' exited abnormally with
> signal 9: Killed: 9 Jul  5 12:16:02 unknown kernel[0] :
> AppleFairplayTextCrypterSession::fairplayOpen() failed, error -42110

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, this is not your fault.  The App Store(s) has been having trouble as of late because it is serving corrupted binaries to consumers.  Contact apple through iTunes connect for resolution, or wait a few days and release an update.  To all developers reading this with pending application updates:

## Wait, please wait!

Other symptoms of this include:

- The app crashes immediately on launch (not even a splash screen shows, just black->crash).
- Affected consumers are spread across many regions (not localized), but some are unaffected.
- Your app/update has been approved fairly recently.
- Mac apps will show *"[App] is damaged and can't be opened.  Delete [App] and download it again from the App Store."*
- The console will print: `AppleFairplayTextCrypterSession::fairplayOopen() failed, error -42110`

The only fix is to delete the app and reinstall (and basically pray for a working copy).  Be assured, **you are not the only one**!  Many major apps from huge companies are being affected by this issue (Angry Birds, NOOOOO).

Corroborated by:

- http://www.marco.org/2012/07/04/app-store-corrupt-binaries
- http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/04/developers_suspect_app_store_mix_up_led_to_corrupt_binaries.html
- http://www.imore.com/2012/07/04/newly-installed-updated-apps-reportedly-crashing-launch-due-corrupt-app-store-binary-bug/
- http://www.forbes.com/sites/anthonykosner/2012/07/05/apple-app-store-encryption-glitch-causes-many-new-app-updates-to-crash-see-list/

Comment: thanks for your info CodaFi, really it is helpful , i will try to release again

Answer (score 0):

> In your Locally tested Application Please Remove it in your Device
>   .After u update or download your updated app in App store